# Trying different cloud solution

Tags: cloud, hybrid

I have tried to use the tencent cloud using their public cloud. I am trying to make my cloud a hybrid solution, but I don't see any on their website.

Has anyone tried to set up a hybrid cloud on tencent?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started please refer to the below links, they are for creating a hybrid infrastructure.

1) [VPN-accessed Hybrid Cloud Deployment](https://cloud.tencent.com/document/product/215/7542)

2) [Direct Connect-accessed Hybrid Cloud Deployment](https://cloud.tencent.com/document/product/215/7543)